# How to pass a function as a prop into a route React js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parameter-passing, react-props

I have taken a look at many other stack overflow questions that look similar to my question but none of them have been any help.

So here is what I am trying to do.

**in App.js:**
Basically I made a function singedInToggleHandler that I want to use in the linked page.

```
signedInToggleHandler = () => {
    this.setState( (prev) => {
      return {signedIn: !prev.signedIn};
    });
  };

<Route path = '/Login' component = {LoginScreen} 
                render = { (props) => (<LoginScreen SignedInToggleHandler = {this.signedInToggleHandler}/>)}/>
```

The last line above is how I am passing in the function.

**I access it then in 
LoginScreen.js**

```
 formType = <SignIn SignedInHandler = {props.SignedInToggleHandler}/>
```

only to pass it to another component SignIn.js

**SignIn.js**

```
function handleSubmit(event){
        console.log("Submitted");
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(email,password);
        const user = SignIn(email,password);
        console.log(user);
        props.SignedInToggleHandler();
    }
```

Now this is the last place I access it. Over here I want to use SignedInToggleHandler() that I got from App.js **but I receive the error message :**

[image]

Thank you so much for your time and help!

Comment: You should be able to find answer from https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is here

```
<Route path = '/Login' component = {LoginScreen} 
                render = { (props) => (<LoginScreen SignedInToggleHandler = {this.signedInToggleHandler}/>)}/>
```

You're using `component` props with `render` function. But as per [doc](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func),

> Warning: `<Route component>` takes precedence over `<Route render>` so don’t use both in the same `<Route>`.

To resolve, remove `component` prop. `render` prop will do it work.

```
<Route path = '/Login' 
                    render = { (props) => (<LoginScreen SignedInToggleHandler = {this.signedInToggleHandler}/>)}/>
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me try this!